# Why use Tags in section "About" on Facebook business page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

There is some rarely used field **Tags** in the "About" section on some Facebook business pages:

[image: Tags field in the About section]

You can select several predefined tags (as in the screenshot) when editing About section. But being a visitor you can't click on these tags, these are not links.

I'm wondering how these tags are used inside Facebook? What do they affect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the answer. If you go to the Review page, you can see now the block, that states:

[image: Ratings and reviews have changed. Learn more]

And if you click on it, you will see a slider with explanatory text:

[image: Easily share the highlights. We've made it simple to share important details through tags and photos]

And you can easily check it in the recommendation form before publishing:

[image: Facebook suggests tags for you recommendation]

So the main purpose of these tags is obviously to be **highlights in the recommendations**:

[image: Tags in a published recommendation]

Apparently when you suggest tags for some page, you promote them for adding to that recommendation form. And if the business page has a lot of recommendations with some tags, these tags will be shown on the About page as approved.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but looking at the names of the tags they reminds me of filters that are being used when searching for something. Maybe used for integration with search engines like google etc (Google asks in their 'Local guides' questions like 'Is this place popular among groups?', 'Does this place have wifi?' ,...)

Answer (score 0):

This helps with Facebook's own Search Engine Optimisation. It means that you are more likely to appear in search results if a user searches for one or more of these tag words.

Comment: Could you please provide any source links for that statement?

Comment: I got beaten to it, I'd have gone with the keywords mentioned above, but I assumed that it eventually linked into highlights/recommendations that you mention below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a *SEO technique* so Facebook Users searching for businesses, in basic terms, can find them - hopefully tagged so they meet their needs, wants, and location.

[image: Keyword SEO tag]

You can see in the marked example image above, the tagged business's profile is marked with Search Engine Optimization in the CSS script.

**Those particular business profile tags are a user-facing feature that let's Facebook's search engine connect customers/clients to businesses.**

Comment: Unfortunately, these are not _tags_, these are _categories_ on your screenshot.